# Extract a word from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking a way with regex to extract the word "MONT" from a sentence without space. And I would like to extract the next number after "WORD

For example :

```
s = valoirfinalieMONT:23maning => MONT 23

s = montdj34meaing  => mont 34

s = thisisthelastmontitwillwork98help => mont 98
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So... What regexes did you try?

Comment: `"(mont|MONT).*?(\d+)"`

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks ! please what if if have a date like s='valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012MONT:23,00maning ' and I want to also extract 13-10-12 13/10/2012 MONT 23,00 . thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try like this.

> `re.I` is for case insensitive match. You can check https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for more details.

```
import re

s = "valoirfinalieMONT:23maning"
s2 = "montdj34meaing"
s3 = "thisisthelastmontitwillwork98help"

m = re.match(r".*(?P<name>mont)\D+(?P<number>\d+).*", s, re.I)
print(m.group(1)) # MONT
print(m.group(2)) # 23

# Same as above (2nd way)
print(m.group('name'));
print(m.group('number'))

m2 = re.match(r".*(?P<name>mont)\D+(?P<number>\d+).*", s2, re.I)
print(m2.group(1)) # mont
print(m2.group(2)) # 34

m3 = re.match(r".*(?P<name>mont)\D+(?P<number>\d+).*", s3, re.I)
print(m3.group(1)) # mont
print(m3.group(2)) # 98
```

Here is the solution to your question that you mentioned in comment.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = 'valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012MONT:23,00maning';
>>> m = re.match(r".*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}).*(MONT).*(\d{2},\
d{2})", s, re.I)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 43), match='valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012M
ONT:23,00'>
>>>
>>> m.group(0)
'valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012MONT:23,00'
>>>
>>> d = m.group(1)
>>> d
'13-10-2012'
>>> arr = d.split("-")
>>> arr
['13', '10', '2012']
>>>
>>> '-'.join(arr[:2] + [arr[2][-2:]])
'13-10-12'
>>>
>>> ans1 = '-'.join(arr[:2] + [arr[2][-2:]])
>>> ans1
'13-10-12'
>>>
>>> ans2 = m.group(2)
>>> ans2
'13/10/2012'
>>>
>>> ans3 = m.group(3)
>>> ans3
'MONT'
>>>
>>> ans4 = m.group(4)
>>> ans4
'23,00'
>>>
>>> output = ' '.join([ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4])
>>> output
'13-10-12 13/10/2012 MONT 23,00'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks ! please what if if have a date like s='valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012MONT:23,00maning ' and I want to also extract 13-10-12 13/10/2012 MONT 23,00 . thanks for your help

Comment: `@atomi`, I have updated my answer with solution to this too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import re

s='valoirfinalieMONT:23maning '
print(re.findall('(mont)\D*(\d*)', s, re.IGNORECASE))
```

the regex will capture 'mont' any number of non digit(\D) characters and then any number of digits(\d)

the ignore case is added so mont and MONT and MoNt and such will also be captured

Comment: Thanks ! please what if if have a date like s='valoir13-10-2012finalie13/10/2012MONT:23,00maning ' and I want to also extract 13-10-12 13/10/2012 MONT 23,00   .   thanks for your help